# PSQL login - error: FATAL: role "User" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, authentication, psql, fatal-error

Windows 10 user trying to either delete a role permanently so the error doesn't show up or create a superuser with no password.

Been searching for hours to no avail.  Tried:

Creating a new user and database with
CREATE USER Nistic SUPERUSER;
CREATE DATABASE registration WITH OWNER Nistic;

The role was successfully created, but upon logging out, and back in, typing "psql" into the terminal will still bring up the same error.  [EDIT] I can login with the postgres username by typing psql -U postgres, but for whatever reason the default username is still set to Nistic.

I've already checked the conf file and set all the methods to trust.  I tried dropping the user and recreating the user.

I just wanted the title to include User to be more general, despite showing Nistic above.

I've pretty much tried everything else that I could find on SO.

Please help, thank you.

Screen below to show some of the oddness (please read each line before commenting - the issue is that after getting rid of Nistic, it still expects Nistic) [image]

Comment: If you can't log in with `psql` how are doing the `CREATE USER` and `CREATE DATABASE`?  Also, however you are doing it, what shows up as the user name? Do you have more then one instance of Postgres running and if so are you sure you are connecting to the correct one. In addition are you sure you are editing the correct `pg_hba.conf` file?

Comment: I can login with psql -U postgres and that's it.  The create commands definitely work.  Sorry I was hesitant to provide that info because I didn't want to sound like I was belittling anyone in fact, but yes I tried all of that, and I *am* sure that I was editing the correct file (pg_hba.conf).

Comment: Looks to me like the env var `PGUSER` has been set. See [Env variables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html).  I don't use Windows enough anymore to tell you how to check for that. That would automatically do the the equivalent pf `-U Nistic` when using `psql` without a `-U <some_user>`. Otherwise the default for `-U` in absence of specifying it with `psql` would be the OS user name `foste`. In meantime you will need to force the user name by specifying `-U <some_name>`.

Comment: The username you was created was all lower-case, since you didn't put the name in double quotes in the SQL.  But the one you were trying to log in as had a capital.

Comment: I can't believe it, but that was the correct answered, @jjanes.  I overlooked this because I thought all the roles were automatically made lowercase, and didn't realize you could change that with quotes.

Comment: What I'm confused about is your terminal session does not show you explicitly setting the user(-U) to Nistic. So where was it coming from?

Comment: I think that wherever the default is being set for the username is somewhere else - and you might be right that it's something like an environment variable @AdrianKlaver However it's not in the standard place that windows stores environment variables from when I looked, so I had to just recreate Nistic to login, and now it works with plain old "psql".

Comment: Have you searched the Registry for `PGUSER`? I would be concerned that there is something that you don't know about setting a user name.